# Java Architecture - should commonly used classes be passed around in constructors?

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture

I'm designing a GUI desktop app in Java, which has a tabbed interface (like the tabs in your browser).

The `MainWindow` class creates the tabbed window, loading other SWT classes that have the code for each tab, e.g. `Tab1Composite`, `Tab2Composite`. There are also classes which handle actions for toolbar menus, and so rely on `MainWindow` for things like localisation (bundles), switching between tabs etc.

Up to now I've been passing the `MainWindow` instance around in the constructor to the other classes. This seems like "good practice", but I can't help but notice how much simpler my code would be if I just made all the necessary variables and methods static.

Any thoughts on which approach I should use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Good practice" means writing code that can be understood, reused, and expanded.  Sometimes quick-and-dirty makes more sense, but code usually lives longer and harder than we expect, and doing it right is good practice even if it does not.

Your main window is a good concept to start with.  It is a set of data needed in many places.  The necessity of passing it down "through the 9 intervening layers" looks awkward, but it makes it plain that *each* of those 9 layer methods, considered as a cohesive whole, does indeed *need* the information in MainWindow.  Using global variables would hide this need and be a sort of practical joke played on anyone trying to maintain or enhance the code.

However, MainWindow also creates windows and tabs and things.  This *does not* need to be passed down, so I'd create another class to use to pass down the information.  This simplifies things.  Our future maintenance person (it could be you) looking at the call from layer 4 to layer 5 no longer needs to puzzle over why layer 5 needs to create tabs.  It might make sense to make several such classes to minimize the amount of information that goes where it is not needed.

The next step would be to note that the objects that actually use this information do not know or care much about MainWindow.  In time they might get used in completely different programs, or they might get used in different ways in this program.  *The information they get might not come from MainWindow.*  What they want is not a class instance, but an interface instance.  Switch to interfaces and your code becomes simpler and far more flexible.

It is best not to get too carried away with all this.  My point is not that you should do a lot of work right now.  Rather, you want to keep in mind your direction if your project continues to go well.

(Note that public fields and static methods *do not* work well with Java interfaces!  Avoid them.)

Answer (score 2):

If you won't be creating any instances of your MainWindow class, then I would make the shared members static. However, non-static members can't be referenced from a static context, so if in your now-static methods you use other non-static methods and variables, they would have to be static too.

Basically you'll be assigning a fixed memory location for them, and so just referencing them statically isn't bad. However, I've always managed to dodge having to make things static. If you find that you have to make **a lot** of members static, reconsider the structure of your program.

Try to avoid making anything static (other than constants). Seperating your GUI from the "work" is the right thing to do. See your program as a tree, and structure it such that an object that is created wouldn't need to have to call to something above it in the tree. Of course this isn't always possible but it makes testing, expanding and debugging easier (in most cases).

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on how you want to make your program. I would say, if you plan on making more than one MainWindow, then making it static would probably not be a good idea. Otherwise, I'm not entirely sure what the drawbacks of making the MainWindow static would be. (Asides from only being able to reference static variables and methods from within MainWindow.)

On the other hand, you could encapsulate the tabs using an interface within a MainWindow class to allow for multiple MainWindow classes with no confusion. This seems to me to be best if the tabs heavily relied upon the MainWindow. (This is similar to mort's answer, I believe.)

To me "good practice" is supposed to mean "good programming," so if your code seems to work better with the static reference, then use it. Just make sure to keep a back-up plan in case something goes wrong.

Then again, Java isn't my preferred language, so I may have a few concepts jumbled.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the MainWindow like a singleton.

Comment: Thought we all decided they were evil?

Comment: Singletons are evil, but nevertheless, every now and then they do have some advantages!

Comment: A singleton would not be an advantage here, unless we don't care about ease of testing.

Answer (score 1):

I only do a little GUI work, but I've been thinking about this problem. I think the right way to do it is to first make sure you have a clean separation between your presentation classes (widgets/components) and the logic behind them, largely using callback interfaces that let you exchange messages back and forth across the layers. For a good-sized application, I'd use a DI framework to manage the "logic" objects in the background. Then all that's needed is some framework code--there may already be a framework for this that I don't know of--that lets your presentation objects be easily wired with the beans managed by your DI container. Avoid static anything at all costs. This is exactly the wrong application for it unless you don't care about testing at all.

Comment: We once did this in a rather big project using the Spring framework - it worked out really fine, but: you have to do a lot of wiring, which, in the end, is basically the same as passing references to the logic object along to the UI objects.

Comment: @mort: Maybe I didn't do a good job describing it. The way I envision it, it would be enormously different from passing references around the objects. For a GUI object buried 10 layers deep, you wouldn't have to pass a reference through the 9 intervening layers, which may not need it, to get down there. That's a vast improvement.

Comment: I think what you mean is commonly revered to dependency injection. You described the biggest advantage yourself - but if you don't have 10 layers, the advantage is not that big - probably not big enough, to introduce a new framework. Another advantage would be that you can easily inject different objects or mocks for e.g. testing.

Comment: @mort: yes, "DI" = dependency injection. It's such a widespread concept today that I'm assuming everyone is basically familiar with the advantages to using such a framework.

Comment: sorry, I think I didn't recognize that DI was dependency injections when I read your post

Answer (score 0):

One different approach for the localisation problem would be to start at your root panel or frame and then recursively walk through all your components. Thus, only UI-components that can cause a local change need a reference to your root panel or frame.

Answer (score 0):

To me, its very bad to pass parent object to child object, and if it is a swing component it should never be done.

Answer (score 0):

Something very handy for your case I just thought of tonight:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getRootPane()